# Html5 Cache Manifest not working correctly

Tags: html, offline-caching, cache-manifest

I am starting to work with offline webapps.

I made a cache manifest for a test site but i cant get it to work.

I trying that when offline it redirect from index.html to offline.html but it just download index.html and shows it.

This is my cache manifest:

```
CACHE MANIFEST

FALLBACK:
./ ./offline.html
```

Inside index.html there is just one line:

```
Hello this is a test, you are online
```

This is offline.html

```
<html manifest='cmanifest'>
<head></head>
<body>you are offline now</body>
</html>
```

**UPDATE**

Now I have this problem:

I add a link that should go to one site when online and another when offline, but it just loads online.html all the time.

My index.html is like this now:

```
<html>
<a href='online.html'>Ir a online.html</a>
</html>
```

And my cache is like this:

```
CACHE MANIFEST

#v2

FALLBACK:
./online ./offline.html

NETWORK:
*
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found the solution myself.

I had this line missing:

```
NETWORK:
*
```